Windows 10 glitch. When maximizing a window, its upper part becomes kind of transparent
I encountered a strange bug in Windows 10, you can watch a video of this bug here.
Under circumstances that are not clear to me (which I can't exactly reproduce), there is a glitch that causes the upper part of the window to become kind of transparent when maximizing the window. You can interact with objects in this “transparent” area with the mouse. However, these objects are not visible due to the glitch.
In order to solve the problem, I removed the tasks one by one in Task Manager, tried to restart Explorer, but it didn't fix the problem.
The only way out is to reboot, but after doing something unknown to me, the problem reappears.
Please recommend me the steps to determine the cause of the problem.
Have you faced this problem too?
How can it be fixed?

First thing is to try repairing Windows with DISM and SFC, https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image . Second, try to figure out what causes the issue, if SFC and DISM don't fix it -- most likely, it is some "popup" on your machine, whether an app or malware, covering the window.

Turning the monitors off and on solves this problem.
I have two monitors installed. When the monitors are turned on, the location of application windows changes. All windows are moved to the first monitor (main monitor). Probably this bug is somehow related to the presence of two monitors.
